# How to get relatedModel records of trashed throughModel in laravel hasManyThrough relationship

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

I have three models `User`, `Customer`, `Message`.

In User model I have:

```
public function customers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Customer::class);
}

public function messages()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Message::class, Customer::class);
}
```

while I am using softDeletes trait in Customer model.

Now in my controller while returning User's messages like so

```
$messages  = auth()->user()->messages()->paginate(30);
```

I am unable to get messages that belongs to trashed customer.

Suggest a solution please. I am not using softDeletes in User and Message model.

Answer (score 0):

hasManyThrough doesn't support softedelete functions like withTrashed.

i think u should try with  another relation model

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like follow :

```
$user->messages()->withTrashedParents()->withTrashed();
```